# Matlab-Error-Variable might be used before it is defined

Tags: matlab, class, object-oriented-analysis, matlab-compiler

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMeL5.jpg)I have defined some classes and two of them Called "Global" &"GlobalFlag".
All the classes are in one folder and same path.
But in another related class I got this warning "Variable might be used before it is defined" and also after running the main code I get the error "Global is not found in the current folder or on the MATLAB path, but exists in:..."

Everything looks correct and all the classes and main code are in a same folder.

How can I fix this problem?

In this screenshot "Die" is also an object of a class.

Everything looks correct and all the classes and main code are in a same folder and same path.
The classes "Global" and "GlobalFlag" don't have any warnings.

Main code:

```
   Optimization = Optimization.CalcOptimization(Die,Machine,Alloy,Billet);
```

Error:

```
 'Global' is not found in the current folder or on the MATLAB path, but exists in: ...

  Change the MATLAB current folder or add its folder to the MATLAB path.

  Error in CProfilOptimization/CalcOptimization (line 19)
        Die.SpeedMaxOpt = Global.SpeedMaxOpt;

  Error in main2 (line 153)
  Optimization=
  Optimization.CalcOptimization(Die,Machine,Alloy,Billet);
```

Class CalcOptimization:

```
 function [obj] = CalcOptimization(obj, Die, Machine, Alloy, Billet)

        error = false;  

        Die.SpeedMaxOpt = Global.SpeedMaxOpt;
        Die.ProfilTempMaxOpt = Global.ProfilTempMaxOpt;
        Die.ProfilTempMinOpt = Global.ProfilTempMinOpt;

        Die.DieLoadMaxOpt = Global.DieLoadtMaxOpt;
        Die.DieLoadMinOpt = Global.DieLoadtMinOpt;
        .
        .
        .
 end
```

Comment: Did you `addpath` the directory where these classes are defined?

Comment: yes but only these two classes have this problems.

Comment: Ok, then post a [mre], because from your description there is only one obvious cause and you claim that is not it. Copy-paste code and error messages into your post (no screen shots).